# While Loop Termination issue?

Tags: c++

The following loop, is supposed to terminate when T is entered as the type my following code.
When I enter T to check if loop determine if it terminates I just get a blank line how could I solve this problem?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
void get_user_input(char&, int&, int&, int&, int&);
float compute_item_cost(char, int, int, int, int);
const float pine_cost = 0.89;
const float fir_cost = 1.09;
const float cedar_cost = 2.26;
const float maple_cost = 4.50;
const float oak_cost = 3.10;
int main()
{
    int quanity, height, width, length;
    string name_of_wood;
    char type;//declare variables
    get_user_input(type, quanity, height, width, length);

    do
    {

        float cost = compute_item_cost(type, quanity, height, width, length);
        if (type == 'P') {
            cout << "Pine" << cost;
            cout << "\n";
            get_user_input(type, quanity, height, width, length);
        }
    }
    while (type != 'T');
    cout << "bad input";
}
void get_user_input(char& type, int& quanity, int& height, int& width, int& length)
{
    cout << "Enter the wood type";
    cin >> type >> quanity >> height >> width >> length;
}
float compute_item_cost(char type, int quanity, int height, int width, int length)
{
    float compute_cost;
    float price;
    if (type == 'P') {
        compute_cost = (height*width*length) / 12.0;
        return compute_cost*quanity*pine_cost;
    }
    //compute_cost = (height*width*length) / 12.0;
    //return compute_cost*quanity*

    compute_cost = (height*width*length) / 12.0;
    return compute_cost*4.50*quanity;
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen?  If I enter T the program ends.

Comment: you have no return statement on your **INT** main()

Comment: @J3STER You don't need one. In C++ a lack of `return` from main default's to `return 0;` It's in the standard.

Comment: @J3STER the return is not required (even if it's better with it), it will compile anyway

Comment: basically if the type == "T" im susposed to output the total of the cost but i havent got that part yet im just checking if i output when the loop does terminate and id dont

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking if you enter T you shouldn't have to enter the rest of the stuff to continue (and terminate the program).  So maybe change `get_user_input` like this:

```
void get_user_input(char& type, int& quanity, int& height, int& width, int& length)
{
    cout << "Enter the wood type";
    cin >> type;
    if (type != 'T')
    {
        cin >> quanity >> height >> width >> length;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to use `std::endl` to flush and insert a newline on `std::cout`, or even use `std::flush`.

```
std::cout << "Some text" << std::endl;
```